# Why does event bubbling not work?

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling, dom-events

I thought I understand event bubbling but my code does not work as expected:

```
<div id="write">
    <form method="post" tabindex="1" onsubmit="myfunc()">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input />Another form element
        <input />Another form element
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<p>Some other text and images...</p>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<script>
    //var formele = document.querySelectorAll("#write form, #write form *");
    var formele = document.querySelectorAll("#write form");
    for (var i = 0; i < formele.length; i++) {
        formele[i].addEventListener("focus", function () {
            overlay.classList.add("active");
        });
        formele[i].addEventListener("focusout", function () {
            overlay.classList.remove("active");
        });
    }
</script>
```

This code should darken the rest of the page when the form or an element inside gets focus or is clicked. I understood event bubbling in the following way:
When a child of the form gets focus it has no event listener added. Thus the focus event bubbles up to the form element and triggers it's event listener.
However it doesn't work that way: If I add the event listener to the form only nothing happens when a textarea or input inside is clicked. I have to add event listeners to the child elements too in order to get it work.
Can anyone explain? Obviously my understanding of event bubbling is wrong somehow.

Comment: Not all events bubble. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus you may want focusin instead.

Comment: overlay is undefined?

Comment: @Kebin B That's the reason, thanks for this hint. Thus my understanding was correct.

Comment: @Jonas w overlay is defined here: <div id="overlay"></div>
Which browser did you use?